# What is the result type of x in if (x(y)) in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm confused while reviewing for finals and don't understand this topic with if statements?

```
if (x(y)){...}
```

What is the result type of x and can some explain it?

Comment: It's used as the condition of an `if` statement so it has to be `boolean`

Comment: assuming the code compiles then the result of `x` must always be a boolean. don't get confused with javascript.

Comment: What exactly does "result type" mean here? Just the type of the expression `x(y)` or something else?

Comment: there must be more to this it looks like x is a function and y the parameter passed to it

Comment: It was a sample question and the answer wasn't given. Thats all the info we have

Comment: @LiamKr: One important takeaway from this is that questions in tests for programming knowledge are frequently confused, worded in sloppy ways, and fixated on a particular way of thinking about the problem. Don't worry overmuch about learning the right answers for the test, since sometimes the right answer for the test is misleading or flat-out wrong in reality. Learn the subject (in this case, the syntax of the Java language), and then you'll be able to see questions like this and figure out the answer they want you to give, at least most of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x()` statement is a method call with a parameter of `y` which returns a `boolean` for the evaluation.

Comment: Just guessing about the downvote: you didn't mention `Boolean`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I stated it in the opening answer. I did not even edit it in.

Comment: You mention `boolean`, not `Boolean`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Huh? Is there a difference for the question?

Comment: Well, one is a class, the other is a primitive. Anyway, at this point I see there's one downvote for all the answers including the one quoting the freaking language standard, so I guess it's just someone trolling.

Comment: @TimCastelijns well, you're entitled to your opinion, of course. The question may be garbage (IMHO it's not, it just shows little understanding), but the answers seem in earnest (and correct).

Comment: And little research but yeah the op does seem lost and maybe prodding them rather than jumping on them is a better idea

Comment: @TimCastelijns: That's a good reason to downvote a question, but not a good reason to downvote an answer. And while I agree that the question is ill-formed at best, it is on-topic, focused, and a good reference topic: all things that I think are *good* attributes for a Stack Overflow question. And although it doesn't happen to be the case here, in many languages there are subtle and important nuances to simple bits of syntax like this (I'm looking at you, C++), which make for *excellent* Stack Overflow questions and answers.

Comment: @TimCastelijns: I'm partial of course, but I don't think my answer could be considered "speculation" here: all it does is quote the spec. If the expression has any type other than `boolean` or `Boolean`, a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: @TimCastelijns: In any case, I actually feel that this kind of question ("given a bit of code that looks like this, what can I *know* to be true about it") is actually a very useful question, because in the real world, I have to deal with tiny out-of-context snippets of code like this all the time (e.g. when code-reviewing diffs). I would much rather have a question like this than yet another "I decided to build an app that does (magical thing) but I have never written code before, please help me do everything" question -- *that's* what I would call a "not useful" question.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [Java Language Specification section 14.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9), "The `if` statement":

> ```
> IfThenStatement:
>     if ( Expression ) Statement
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The *Expression* must have type `boolean` or `Boolean`, or a compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is a method, `y` is it's parameter.

`Method x` take `parameter y` and return a `boolean` or `Boolean`, let's say it `z`,  then it execute like `if(z)`.

For example:

```
boolean x(int y) {
    if (y == 0) {
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

and

```
int y = 1;
if(x(y)) {
    System.out.print("y is zero");
}
```

Comment: @TimCastelijns Typo, fixed.